# Сложить время двух таймеров

Tags: java, android, datetime, таймер

Ребята кто может подсказать  куда смотреть или где почитать. Как мне сложить время. У нас есть таймер он работает, мы его останавливаем и сохраняем его значение(время которое он проработал).Запускаем снова таймер , он опять работает , останавливаем, и нужно прибавить текущее время таймера к тому времени которые мы сохранили до этого.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textViewTimer;
private TextView textViewTotalTime;
private boolean isTimerWorking = false;
private int sec = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textViewTimer = findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
    textViewTotalTime = findViewById(R.id.tvTotalTime);
    run();
}

public void onClickStartTimer(View view) {
    isTimerWorking = true;
}
public void onClickStopTimer(View view) {
    isTimerWorking = false;
}
public void onClickResetTime(View view) {
    isTimerWorking = false;
    sec = 0;
}
```

public void onClickSaveTime(View view) {

```
    try {



        //Берем время основного таймера
    String timerTime = String.valueOf(textViewTimer.getText());

    String[] strHourMinSec = timerTime.split(":");
    int[] numHourMinSec = new int[3];
    int hCur =  numHourMinSec[0] = Integer.parseInt(strHourMinSec[0]);
    int mCur =  numHourMinSec[1] = Integer.parseInt(strHourMinSec[1]);
    int sCur =  numHourMinSec[2] = Integer.parseInt(strHourMinSec[2]);

    //Заносим часы минуты секунды основного таймера в переменную LocalTime
    LocalTime totalT = LocalTime.of(hCur, mCur, sCur);

    //извлекаем время из основного таймера и заносим в общий
    textViewTotalTime.setText(totalT.toString());

    String totalTime = String.valueOf(textViewTotalTime.getText());

    String[] strTotalHourMinSec = totalTime.split(":");
    int[] numTotalHourMinSec = new int[3];
    int hTot = numTotalHourMinSec[0] = Integer.parseInt(strTotalHourMinSec[0]);
    int mTot = numTotalHourMinSec[1] = Integer.parseInt(strTotalHourMinSec[1]);
    int sTot = numTotalHourMinSec[2] = Integer.parseInt(strTotalHourMinSec[2]);

    //Добавляем часы минуты секунды в новую переменную LocalTime
    LocalTime allTime = LocalTime.of(hTot, mTot, sTot);

    //Плюсуем время текущего таймера к общему
    allTime.plusHours(hCur);
    allTime.plusMinutes(mCur);
    allTime.plusSeconds(sCur);

    textViewTotalTime.setText(allTime.toString());

    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    }

}
public void run() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int hours = sec / 3600;
            int minutes = (sec % 3600) / 60;
            int secon = sec % 60;

            String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secon);
            textViewTimer.setText(time);

            if (isTimerWorking) {
                sec++;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Для начала стоит хранить время в виде какого то числа, например timestamp, а уже потом его пытаться складывать. Делать арифметические операции со строками как то не очень идея

Comment: в том то и проблема что я не могу понять как мне  эти числа сложить и потом обратно привести ко времени.Я из строки текущего таймера  достаю числа (часы, минуты, секунды) допустим - 01, 30, 50. Достаю из общего времени (часы, минуты , секунды) - 00, 36 , 20.Потом складываю )) и получается какая то ерунда. Я еще далек от программирования, просто увлекаюсь немножко) . Пытался сделать через LocalTime там можно складывать часы минуты секунды, но так до конца и не понял почему они у меня не складывались

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опять решение пришло на свежую голову с утра.)) Почитал про LocalTime и решил сделать через него, добавил в шапку кода переменную общего времени  LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0);
и уже в обработчике кнопки плюсую к ней время текущего таймера, вроде работает ))

```
 public void onClickSaveTime(View view) {

    try {
        //Берем время текущего таймера
        String strCurrentTimer = textViewTimer.getText().toString();

        //разбиваем на массив и заносим в переменные
        String[] strCurrentTimerArr = strCurrentTimer.split(":");
        int[] numCurrentTimerArr = new int[3];
        numCurrentTimerArr[0] = Integer.parseInt(strCurrentTimerArr[0]);
        numCurrentTimerArr[1] = Integer.parseInt(strCurrentTimerArr[1]);
        numCurrentTimerArr[2] = Integer.parseInt(strCurrentTimerArr[2]);
        int cHour = numCurrentTimerArr[0];
        int cMin = numCurrentTimerArr[1];
        int cSec = numCurrentTimerArr[2];

        // создаем LocalTime и сохраняем знаечния текущего таймера часы минуты секунды
        LocalTime timeCurTimer = LocalTime.of(cHour, cMin, cSec);

         //плюсуем к  LocalTime  текущее время
         //LocalTime time - создан в шапке
        time = time.plusHours(timeCurTimer.getHour());
        time = time.plusMinutes(timeCurTimer.getMinute());
        time = time.plusSeconds(timeCurTimer.getSecond());

        textViewTotalTime.setText(time.toString());

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    }
    sec = 0;
}
```

Наверняка есть  решение по проще , кто знает плз подскажите. Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил стринг времени в виджете переводить в date:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

и дальше у вас будет две даты:

```
Date d1 = ...
Date d2 = ...

long sum = d1.getTime() + d2.getTime();

Date sumDate = new Date(sum);
```

по итогу вы получаете третью дату которая равна сумме. [Вот](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-date) как конвертировать стринг в дату и [суммировать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067657/sum-two-dates-in-java).

Comment: У него уже есть числовое значение времени, которое он преобразует в строку . Делать потом еще одну конвертацию из строки в дату как то слишком далекий путь

Comment: @pavlofff, я увидел только сеттинг в textView и все) я с вами согласен что проще конечно сохранять обе переменные в data и потом просто суммировать, но я исходил из того что увидел в вопросе) или вы об этой строке - `String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secon)`?

Comment: переделал с LocalTime не могу понять почему не плюсуется время ... видимо я тупой